# ffmpeg speed up video - Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

In manual it says:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v 'setpts=0.5*PTS' output.mkv
```

But when I run:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v 'setpts=0.5*PTS' speedup.mp4
```

I get an error:

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000002500600] No such filter: 'setpts=0.5*PTS'
Error opening filters!
```

Not sure if it means that filter can't be opened at all or simply this filter is not available.

How do I run it correctly? Or maybe my release does not support it, then where can I get the release that would work right? **Win32/x64 binary**

Comment: move the quote... try -filter:v -setpts='....'

Comment: Try leaving the quotes away. At the time of writing, my PC is running: "ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -r 30 -filter:v setpts=1/100*PTS -an output.mp4"

Answer (score 16):

Use both `setpts` and `atempo` to speed up both video and audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input-video.mp4 -vf "setpts=0.68*PTS" -filter:a "atempo=1.467" output-video.mp4
```

From: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

You'll have to do the right math for the numbers, of course.  The `setpts` needs to be smaller to make the video go faster, but `atempo` needs to be larger to speed up the audio.

`Audio value needed = 1 / Video value`

Answer (score 2):

if you have your ffmpeg.exe (mine for  windows) for ex you can list all the available filters with this command line, you can edit the  txt file c:\filters.txt to see them.

**ffmpeg -filters > c:\yfilters.txt**

in mine i can se the filter SETPS (VIDEO TO VIDEO only):

**setpts           V->V       Set PTS for the output video frame.**

your command line is correct and work with the ffmpeg version that have this filter(try to download the latest version)

this command line works also  for me :
**ffmpeg -i video_input -vf  "setpts=factor*PTS"  video_output**

the factor can be :

1.**for speeding the video 0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8..(<1)**

2.for **slowing the video:1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,10.0... (>1)**

Comment: This does not alter the audio duration/speed together with the video speed change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes. e.g. `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" speedup.mp4`